# Extension is missing delivery option

Tags: configuration, custom-product-type

Recently i had installed a custom product type (custom module),but then it is missing delivery option .Is configuration from the custom module's end? or magento's delivery method end?

Comment: if you are referring to shipping methods then configuration should be on magento's end

Comment: When i m testing on buying a simple product, delivery option is visible & available. But on my custom product .Not a single delivery method are shown.

Comment: is your custom product a simple product type as well?

Comment: No it isn't,how do i make magento to 'recognise' the custom product?

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom product also being treated the same as a simple? Does it have a weight? Products without weight are virtual and therefore not delivered but downloaded.

Comment: I have placed ts_dimension_weight & length & height on a certain attribute set(set like bags)  .But when I m adding product and configuring the product into the attritube set.Weight, Length & Height doesn't show up. Why is that happening?

Comment: Do the dimensions transfer across on simples okay or is it the custom product type that only has issue?

Comment: Only custom product type has issue on dimension ,simple are fine

Comment: I think it will be best to reach out to extension developers